# Excel VBA - get add-in project name

Tags: vba, excel-2010

I've converted a VBA-driven project from a normal Excel 2010 worksheet to an add-in, and would like to get the name of the VBA project via software.

(I have an 'About...' button that I have an annoying tendency to forget to update when the project is updated, and want to look up the VBA project name to use in the MsgBox.)

When the code is in worksheet form, this call in my `About...` button callback routine works just fine:

`Application.VBE.ActiveVBProject.Name`

However, when the code is in add-in format, this call returns the name of the VBA project for the current worksheet (i.e.`VBAProject`), not the add-in.

Is there an non-convoluted method to get the currently executing add-in project name? I see that there are some methods that enumerate the add-ins, and I could search them one by one for an name that matches a pattern, but that seems cumbersome.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How about `ThisWorkbook.VBproject.Name`?

Comment: That seems to do the trick. It seems odd (to me) that the add-in realizes that it is a different workbook, but the active VB project called by my first attempt isn't where execution is happening.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand what seems odd, but I'll try to clarify. `ThisWorkbook` always refers to the workbook the code is in. If it's coded inside an addin, it will refer to the properties of that addin/workbook.

Comment: Sorry - `ThisWorkbook` is clear. I'm not sure why VBE.ActiveProject was pointing away from where execution was happening.

Comment: I see. According to Excel help, "The ActiveVBProject property returns the project that is selected in the Project window or the project in which the components are selected." So, I'd say it correlates somewhat to the `ActiveWorkbook`, which isn't what you want.

Comment: On EE.SE we usually allow a grace period before accepting an answer, just in case someone else has something to add, but your answer was pretty concise and to the point, so no point in prolonging the inevitable.

Answer (score 3):

The [currently accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18212647/8488913) `ThisWorkbook.VBproject.Name` only works if user has enabled the **Trust access to the VBA project object model**.

The following function does not require such access:

```
Public Function ProjectName() As String
    On Error Resume Next
    Err.Raise 5
    ProjectName = Err.Source
    On Error GoTo 0
End Function
```

Moreover, this function is compatible with any application, not just Excel.